# Замена телефонного номера на другой

Tags: javascript

Есть телефонный номер:

```
+9 (999) 999-99-99
```

(формат любой, т.е. между цифрами могут стоять пробелы, дефисы, скобки, плюсы, разная другая лабуда)
И есть произвольные N цифр, скажем

```
12345678900
```

N соответствует первому примеру.
Задача заменить цифры из первого номера на цифры из второго в яваскрипте.

Хотелось бы что-то менее костыльное, чем следующая конструкция:

```
var num = '+7 999 123 32 32',
    newnum = '12345678900'.split('');

num = num.replace(/\d/g,'X');//Заменяем все на любой символ, который не встречается в телефонных номерах)
for(i=0;i<newnum.length;i++){//В цикле меняем последовательно все решетки на цифры нового номера
    num = num.replace(/X/,newnum[i]);
}
alert(num);
```

Я более чем уверен, что есть какая-то суперфункция, типа

```
num = num.split('магия').superfunction(newnumber).join('другая магия');
```

UPD:
Есть плагины, но у меня тока обфусцированные версии, а хотелоссь бы понять как работает
UPD2: 
в американских номерах X встречается. Поэтому там можно что-то типа вопросительного знака заюзать

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
num = num.replace(/\d/g, function() {
    return newnum.shift();
});
```

Comment: Можно еще конеш обойтись без сплита нового номера, просто добавьте счетчик, а в функции измените на:

    return newnum[i++];

Comment: Проверку на 'underfined' - если num > newnum, ну и предусмотреть обратный случай

Comment: @xfloooo ну такого не было в задаче, а тс думаю это предусмотрит, если потребуется)

Comment: Ыыы)) Все время про вызов функции забываю. Тем не менее, это как раз тот самый магический способ, который я искал.

Answer (score 1):

https://jsfiddle.net/j3j8jwav/1/

В качестве заполнителя можно указать любой символ.

Comment: в ff не работает.

Comment: @lampa, да, есть такое, забыл, что у FF нету `elem.innerText()`.  
Вот тут рабочий вариант: https://jsfiddle.net/j3j8jwav/1/

Comment: @TheDoctor ага, не забывайте, пару больших проектов видел, которые из-за этого и не работали.